# Get a column to represent data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry if my question wasn't clear before, i updated it hope it makes more sense now.

I have 2 tables:

```
Servers (Server,IP,OS)
IPs (IP,Ping,Server)
```

I have configured a foreign key so that any ip inserted to "Servers" will have to exist on "IPs".

Now, i would like that every time i insert a record to the "Servers" table, the Server will automatically be created in the "IPs" table in corresponding IP (the IPs table already contains all of the possible ip addresses with NULL in the Server column). for example:

1. IPs table looks like this:

   IP Ping Server

   1.1.1.1  True     Null
   1.1.1.2  True     Null
   1.1.1.3  True     Null
2. insert into Servers table: Server=srv1 IP=1.1.1.1 OS=Win2008R2
3. IPs table is automatically updated and now looks like this:

   IP       Ping     Server

   1.1.1.1  True     **Srv1**
   1.1.1.2  True     Null
   1.1.1.3  True     Null

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a trigger

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: First, I agree with MegaTron that more details are needed. Second, there is no `Server` column in the `IPs` table, so you must mean `Name`. Third, why do you have `IP` in the `Servers` table and the `IPs` table?

Answer (score 0):

You need a query to join the two tables together in order to relate the two tables by the common field, which is IP.

```
SELECT * 
FROM SERVERs 
inner join IPs 
ON Servers.IP = IPs.IP
```